# Get value of bit from bytes | Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, byte, nsdata

i need an help.
So i'm getting bytes from BLE device, and i need to get a battery level.
This is returned by Uint8 Bytes.
So my works code (with comment):

```
       func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print("\n------DATASTRING------\n")
        let data = characteristic.value ?? NSData() as Data

//        let stringInt = String.init(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? ""
//        let int = UInt32.init(stringInt)
//        print(int ?? 000)
        print(data as NSData)


        //        if data != nil {
//            let dataString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
//            print("\n------DATASTRING------\n")
//            print(dataString ?? "")
//        } else {
//            print("\n------DATASTRING EMPTY------\n")
//        }
    }
```

data content:

[image]

as you can see i have number 86 (first bit of byte), this is the batter level, but i can't read it. So how can i get this integer data 86 from byte ? 
I saw online some solution that you can see in the comment code, but nothing works.
I need an help i'm new of swift 5.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

86 is the first *byte* (not the first bit) of the data. You get it with

```
let level = data[0]
```

(after checking that `data` is not empty).

Comment: @Mr.Developer It's OK, you were just a *bit* confused. :)

Comment: @Martin R ahahahha ya